# how to receive output after clicking an extjs button via phantomjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, phantomjs, extjs4.2

I am writing a script through which a user can download an excel sheet from the command-line rather than clicking the 'Export to Excel' button on an internal website. I already have an 'Export to Excel' button on my ExtJS UI and I want to reuse that functionality in my script.

I am able to load the page and can check that `Ext` is available. I believe I need to call `button.handler()` to simulate clicking the button. In fact it does download the excel sheet when invoked from firebug.

I have come up with this till now, using phantomjs. Basically an amalgum of [loadspeed.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/loadspeed.js) and [waitfor.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js).

```
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};

var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
t, address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit();
}

t = Date.now();
address = system.args[1];

page.open(address, function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL to load the address');
    } else {
        t = Date.now() - t;
        console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
        waitFor(function() {
            var btn = page.evaluate(function() {
                return Ext.getCmp('export_to_excel_btn');
            });
            return btn !== null;
        },
        function() {
            var xl;
            waitFor(function() {
                xl = page.evaluate(function() {
                    var btn = Ext.getCmp('export_to_excel_btn');
                    return btn.handler(); // Never works.
                });
                console.log(xl)
                return xl !== null;
            },
            function() {
                console.log('In the inner waitFor');
                phantom.exit();
            }, 10000);
        }, 10000);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the inner `waitFor` always times out. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS cannot download a file if you just click the corresponding button. You have to explicitly download the file through XMLHttpRequest. To do that, you have to reverse engineer the JavaScript code that downloads the file.

```js
function download(page, url) {
    return page.evaluate(function(url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, false);
        xhr.send();
        return xhr.responseText;
    }, url);
}
```

Even if you click on the element and then try to wait for the request with [`page.onResourceRequested`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html) and then trigger the `download` with the now known url, cannot work because the request isn't sent by PhantomJS.